# glDrawArrays problems on retina display

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw simple square with size of full screen with glDrawArray method in cocos2d. When retina is disabled everything draws as expected but when enabled - everything is half as big as it should be. (it seems like coordinate system in glDrawArray is not in points but in pixels)

Other draw functions works as expected but since I am drawing complicated shapes we have to use glDrawArray since it is much faster.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
-(void) draw
{
    CGPoint box[4];
    CGPoint boxTex[4];

    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    //float boxSize = winSize.width;

    box[0] = ccp(0,winSize.height); // top left
    box[1] = ccp(0,0); // bottom left
    box[2] = ccp(winSize.width,winSize.height);
    box[3] = ccp(winSize.width,0);

    boxTex[0] = ccp(0,1);
    boxTex[1] = ccp(0,0);
    boxTex[2] = ccp(1,1);
    boxTex[3] = ccp(1,0);

    // texture backround
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.sprite.texture.name);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, box);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, boxTex);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the drawing is done in pixels, so in order to handle proper rendering on the retina display as well, you need to multiply your vertices by CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR():

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    box[i] = ccpMult(box[i], CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
```

CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR returns 2 on retina devices instead of 1, so using it should take care of the scaling.